# Why is text paragraph width not 100% of div on AppleWebKit/537.36?

Tags: html, css

This issue might have something to do with zoom level. It happens on AppleWebKit/537.36.

Sometimes the width of a text paragraph (p tag) is not 100% of the width of its parent div. Why is that so?

When a p tag has background-color:#FFFFFF, the width is 100%, but if there is background-color:transparent or no background-color, the width is not 100%.

Help me, please.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="fi" />
</head>

<body style="background-color:blue">
<div style="width:600px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
<p>This width is not 100% - This width is not 100% - This width is not 100% - This width is not 100%</p>

<p style="background-color:transparent">This width is not 100% - This width is not 100% - This width is not 100% - This width is not 100%</p>

<p style="background-color:#FFFFFF">This width is 100% - This width is 100% - This width is 100% - This width is 100%</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Um, what does AppleWebKit/537.36 have to do with Android?

Comment: My problem occurs on my mobile phone. It has Android 4.4.4 and AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36.